# I18n routes: missing required keys: [:locale]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, i18n-gem

With Rails 4 and I18n.

When i call path like

```
conversation_path(locale: :de, 1)
```

it gives me an error saying

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"frontend/conversations", :id=>1, :locale=>:de} missing required keys: [:locale]
```

routes.rb

```
scope '/:locale' do
  localized do
    scope module: 'frontend' do
      resources :conversations, only: [:index, :show]
    end
  end
end
```

rake routes gives me

```
conversation_de GET /:locale/conversations/:id(.:format) frontend/conversations#show {:locale=>"de"}
conversation_en GET /:locale/conversations/:id(.:format) frontend/conversations#show {:locale=>"en"}
```

am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change in routes.rb

```
scope '/:locale' do
```

to:

```
scope '/:locale', locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join('|')}/ do
```